# Hide caption on the first slide (Nivo Slider)

Tags: slider, nivo-slider

Can you help me to hide the caption only on the first slide in Nivo Slider. I have this code:

```js
$('#slider').nivoSlider({ 
    effect: 'random',                 // Specify sets like: 'fold,fade,sliceDown' 
    slices: 15,                       // For slice animations 
    boxCols: 8,                       // For box animations 
    boxRows: 4,                       // For box animations 
    animSpeed: 500,                   // Slide transition speed 
    pauseTime: 3000,                  // How long each slide will show 
    startSlide: 0,                    // Set starting Slide (0 index) 
    directionNav: true,               // Next & Prev navigation 
    controlNav: true,                 // 1,2,3... navigation 
    controlNavThumbs: false,          // Use thumbnails for Control Nav 
    pauseOnHover: true,               // Stop animation while hovering 
    manualAdvance: false,             // Force manual transitions 
    prevText: 'Prev',                 // Prev directionNav text 
    nextText: 'Next',                 // Next directionNav text 
    randomStart: false,               // Start on a random slide 
    beforeChange: function(){},       // Triggers before a slide transition 
    afterChange: function(){},        // Triggers after a slide transition 
    slideshowEnd: function(){},       // Triggers after all slides have been shown 
    lastSlide: function(){},          // Triggers when last slide is shown 
    afterLoad: function(){}           // Triggers when slider has loaded 
});
```

I need to use something like this construction

```js
FirstSlide: function(){}
```

But I don't how to add to this function the  CSS-parameter:

```css
.nova-caption{display:none;}
```